# Strike /to deliver/give

Tags: meaning

> ... ready to **strike** the moment he could be sure of allies... **to deliver** the last Potter to them. I he **gave** them Harry,  who'd dare say he'd betrayed Lord Voldemort?

My research : 1) Strike means attack or kill.
2) Deliver means to hand over as in "take him to someone in control" or "tell the authority his place".
3) Give means to physically provide.

Question : if he already "striked," that is, killed Harry, how would he "deliver" him and "give" him to his master?

Comment: I know it can be deemed as a stupid question. Though I really have no idea.

Comment: The past tense of _strike_ is _struck_. It doesn't necessarily mean 'to kill' - in this context it probably means 'make a sudden attack' (to kidnap Harry?).

Comment: I don't think that would happen as the castle is protected by Dumbledore.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the story (which I have read, but not recently). You interpreted 'ready to strike' as 'ready to kill Harry', but it doesn't necessarily mean that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on the mistaken idea that "to strike" means "to kill". In the cited context, it simply means "act, take action".